# Wikitude SDK set-up

Tags: android, android-studio, wikitude

I'm new to Wikitudea and I'm trying to get it on the last version of Android Studio and I'm stuck… I followed the instructions of wikitude's video “Set-up Guide. Android Javascript API” and I get these error messages:

- on Gradle sync:

…//WikitudeSDK_Android_5-1-4_2016-03-14_14-50-48/Examples/SDKExamples/build.gradle

Error:(16, 0)

Gradle DSL method not found: 'android()'

Possible causes:

-The project 'SDKExamples' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.

-The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.

- on Gradle build:

Error:(16, 1) A problem occurred evaluating root project 'SDKExamples'.

> Could not find method android() for arguments [build_9gtn2gg2nuca14amc9jhql4mv$_run_closure2@7fd77467] on root project 'SDKExamples'.

Could you please help me? I don't know what to do...

Comment: looks like this could solve your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26243480/could-not-find-method-android-for-arguments-when-building-android-project-from.
Also did you just open the Wikitude Example App in android studio and this problem appeared?